# Telegraf Markup inline keyboard doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

I created a simple item price tracker bot with NodeJS and Telegraf npm library. It includes step wizard and markup inline keyboard. When I press any inline keyboard button 1st time it doesn't call pre-configured action and it does at 2nd attempt only (see pictures below).

1st click
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXeB3.png

2nd click
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIn1H.png

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.TELEGRAM_API)
const Composer = require('telegraf/composer')
const Stage = require('telegraf/stage')
const WizardScene = require('telegraf/scenes/wizard')
const Markup = require('telegraf/markup')
const session = require('telegraf/session')

const items = []
let id
let email
let item
let price

const itemSelector = new Composer()
itemSelector.action("item1", (ctx) => {
    item = "Item 1"
    return ctx.wizard.next()
})
itemSelector.action("item2", (ctx) => {
    item = "Item 2"
    return ctx.wizard.next()
})
itemSelector.action("item3", (ctx) => {
    item = "Item 3"
    return ctx.wizard.next()
})
itemSelector.action("item4", (ctx) => {
    item = "Item 4"
    return ctx.wizard.next()
})

const wizard = new WizardScene(
    "scene",
    ctx => {
        id = ctx.from.id
        ctx.reply("Enter your email address")
        return ctx.wizard.next()
    },
    ctx => {
        email = ctx.message.text
        ctx.reply("Select the required gas price level", Markup.inlineKeyboard([
            Markup.callbackButton("Item 1", "item1"),
            Markup.callbackButton("Item 2", "item2"),
            Markup.callbackButton("Item 3", "item3"),
            Markup.callbackButton("Item 4", "item4"),
        ]).extra())
        return ctx.wizard.next()
    },
    itemSelector,
    ctx => {
        ctx.reply("Enter the required price")
        return ctx.wizard.next()
    },
    ctx => {
        price = parseFloat(ctx.message.text)
        items.push({ id, item, email })
        ctx.reply(`When the ${item} price will be equal or lower than ${price} alert will be send to ${email}`)
        return ctx.scene.leave()
    }
)
const stage = new Stage([wizard])
bot.use(session())
bot.use(stage.middleware())

bot.start((ctx) => {
    ctx.scene.enter('scene')
})

bot.launch()
```